# Why does S3 retrieve speed increase after subsequent calls using StreamReader?

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I am using visual studio to access AWS S3 via the SDK.

I am trying to figure out why after a few successive calls the GetObjectSync object retrieval time cuts down significantly.

Eg - I am accessing my data from eu-west-2 from ap-southeast-2 with transfer acceleration enabled. If I make a few calls in a row, (3 or 4 calls, within 3-5 seconds). My logged GetObjectAsync times will look something like:

```
1.91s
1.82s
1.93s
.3s
.29s
.32s
```

What is happening after these initial 3-4 calls that then enables super fast access and is there anyway I can make the latter calls the status quo?

In this case I am getting the data from a vast distance, but the same thing happens if I access my local machine which is on the same continent (AU).

My GetObjectAsync call response timings might then look like:

```
.29s
.32s
.27s
.03s
.04s
.05s
```

So it appears symptomatic of same, just obviously with reduced latency all round due to geography. If I then stop making calls for a few minutes again, it "resets" and starts from the high latency again.

I'm very latency sensitive so need it to perform at the lower end, always. The issue I also have here is that users might only make 1 call intermittently to my services so in that case they aren't never achieve the luxury of the reduced latency.

I get my S3 file via the following code:

```cs
using (var response = await _s3.GetObjectAsync(request))
{
    sw.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine($"S3 GetObjectAsync: {sw.Elapsed}");
    sw.Reset();
    sw.Start();
    using (var responseStream = response.ResponseStream)
    {
        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine($"S3 ResponseStream: {sw.Elapsed}");
        sw.Reset();
        sw.Start();
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(responseStream))
        {
            result = reader.ReadToEnd();
            sw.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine($"S3 ReadToEnd: {sw.Elapsed}");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: All your stream operations are blocking, you should use the `xxxasync` version of it. My guess is your threadpool is getting exhausted and new threads are getting injected which then restores it.

Answer (score 0):

You're using [`_s3.GetObjectAsync(...)`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/items/S3/MS3GetObjectAsyncGetObjectRequestCancellationToken.html), which is much better than [`_s3.GetObject`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/items/S3/MS3GetObjectGetObjectRequest.html) as it's *asynchronous*, but then you're using `reader.ReadToEnd();` which is *synchronous* and *blocking*.

The reason why it speeds up is not AWS related as you've proven by running the code from various locations but also the fact that Amazon S3 Transfer Acceleration works by essentially "caching" your data at Edge Locations.

I would assume that your application is speeding up due to some form of `StreamReader` object caching by the .NET CLR but that could only be proven by seeing the specific timing outputs that you've mentioned in your code.

Regardless, I would stick with either synchronous or asynchronous, preferably the latter so that would be reading from the stream using [`StreamReader.ReadToEndAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamreader.readtoendasync?view=net-5.0).

This should produce consistent results:

```
using (var response = await _s3.GetObjectAsync(request))
{
    sw.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine($"S3 GetObjectAsync: {sw.Elapsed}");
    sw.Reset();
    sw.Start();
    using (var responseStream = response.ResponseStream)
    {
        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine($"S3 ResponseStream: {sw.Elapsed}");
        sw.Reset();
        sw.Start();
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(responseStream))
        {
            result = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
            sw.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine($"S3 ReadToEnd: {sw.Elapsed}");
        }
    }
}
```

---

Also, if you're reading to eventually write to a file, it's good to be aware of  [`GetObjectResponse.WriteResponseStreamToFileAsync`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/items/S3/MGetObjectResponseWriteResponseStreamToFileAsyncStringBooleanCancellationToken.html) which will encapsulate this logic for you.